# Run a simple AC motor with batteries using a wall charger for double and triple A batteries as the inverter

Tags: inverter, charger

I'm trying to put an electric motor on my bike going from gas to electric and was wondering if somehow I could use a normal battery charger that charges my triple and double AAA batteries as an inverter.

Can I flip the capacitors or do some kind of change to the battery charger to make a 120V 60Hz AC motor run on batteries?

Here are some pics showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: There's no way that little motor has the power to move a bike... You are wanting to convert a gas motor bike to an electric one?

Comment: the battery charger is a one way device ... it does not produce AC power if you insert fully charged cells

Comment: Going from right to left -- the motor is too wimpy to drive a bike, the charger is too wimpy for that motor, and the pictured battery is wimpier than the charger.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to put an electric motor on my bike going from gas to electric and was wondering if somehow I could use a normal battery charger that charges my triple and double AAA batteries as an inverter.
>   Can I flip the capacitors or do some kind of change to the battery charger to make a 120V 60Hz AC motor run on batteries?

Congratulations on your ingenuity but, sadly, no, not in any usefl way.
Even if you could power it in this manner, the motor power would be too low to be useful - a bit of fun maybe, but even if powered properly it would be VERY slow.

There are motors available that are more suitable - but you'd also need a far more substantial battery.

A suitable motor would ideally be low voltage and designed to operate from DC.
An adequate size battery would be a 12V motorcycle battery or a Lithium Io battery pack.

As a motor to investigate the concept a 12V battery powered drill would be far lower power than a small gas engine but a better starting point.

---

**Other input from comments:**

There's no way that little motor has the power to move a bike.

Even a very small 'gas' motor will produce hundreds of Watts. A battery such as the one shown or AA batteries will produce a maximum of a few Watts and for a short period.
An eg 7Ah 12V motorcycle battery will produce about 10 Watts for 6+ hours, 100 Watts for under half and hour and never as much as a small gas motor.

Motor specs: output power 80-100W, loaded speed 10400rpm, voltage 220-240V, Current 1.1A.

The battery charger is a one way device ... it does not produce AC power if you insert fully charged cells.

Comment: The motor might be usable as an "assist"; ebike kits seem to be in the 250W range. Of course you need a LOT more batteries.

Comment: @pjc50  Maybe. You'd need a say 12V -  110VAC inverter and a suitable 12V battery. As Bruce notes, the motor has a loaded speed of 10,000 RPM so gearing it down would be impractical - except maybe if used  to drive a propellor :-). [Examples here](https://www.alibaba.com/hc5420-motor-suppliers.html)